# vba getElementById generated by javascript

Tags: excel, vba, dom, web-scraping

I am currently trying to download the value of a div on the following page: http://www.banrep.gov.co/es/tasa-cambio-del-peso-colombiano-trm   this value of the div is generated with a javascript. Can someone tell me if it is possible to download that value that is generated with javascript with VBA?

[Page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKc5C.png)

this is my code:

```
Sub Basics_Of_Web_Macro()

    Dim myIE As Object
    Dim myIEDoc As Object

    Set myIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    myIE.Visible = True

    myIE.navigate "http://www.banrep.gov.co/es/tasa-cambio-del-peso-colombiano-trm"

    While myIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set myIEDoc = myIE.document


    MsgBox myIEDoc.Title

    MsgBox myIEDoc.getElementById("div_datos").innerText

End Sub
```

Comment: btw it is entirely possible to get that value.

Comment: Sub Basics_Of_Web_Macro()
 
    Dim myIE As Object
    Dim myIEDoc As Object
 
    Set myIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 
    myIE.Visible = True
 
    myIE.navigate "http://www.banrep.gov.co/es/tasa-cambio-del-peso-colombiano-trm"
 
    While myIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set myIEDoc = myIE.document
 

    MsgBox myIEDoc.Title

    MsgBox myIEDoc.getElementById("div_datos").innerText
 
End Sub

Comment: This is my code but when I try to get the value of the div it sends a error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternative url that the page uses to get that content. You can regex out the value from the response. You could generalise the regex more according to use cases.

Try regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/uJhFnD/1)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim s As String, re As Object, p As String
    p = "new Array\(.*, ""\d+,\d+"",""(\d+\.\d+,\d+)""\);"
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://obieebr.banrep.gov.co/analytics/saw.dll?Go&path=%2Fshared%2fSeries%20Estad%c3%adsticas_T%2F1.%20Tasa%20de%20Cambio%20Peso%20Colombiano%2F1.1%20TRM%20-%20Disponible%20desde%20el%2027%20de%20noviembre%20de%201991%2F1.1.6.TCM_TRM%20para%20un%20d%C3%ADa&lang=es&options=rdf&NQUser=publico&NQPassword=publico", False
        .send
        s = .responseText
        Debug.Print GetValue(re, s, p)        
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetValue(ByVal re As Object, inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = pattern
        If .Test(inputString) Then
            GetValue = .Execute(inputString)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            GetValue = "Not found"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Regex explanation:

[image]

Comment: Now I have a similar problem, I am trying to select an option of a dropdown list (tipo de cambio) of this page (http://www.banrep.gov.co/es/monedas-disponibles) but I can not do it ,there is some way to do it, these controls are generated with javascript

Comment: Will have a look later. At dinner now.

Comment: what did you want to do with that new page? You are correct in so far as javascript is running on that page so you need to allow enough time for the [spinner](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C1GCEV_enGB851GB851&ei=7gTyXMXiBqSd1fAPu_CZUA&q=web+page+spinner+images&oq=web+page+spinner+image&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.33i160l2.2719.5784..7578...0.0..0.92.646.10......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i22i30j0j0i13i10i30j33i22i29i30j33i21.fEK9p-npsHE) to disappear. Have a go at different wait conditions e.g. spinner element to disappear

Comment: or another element to be present or a nodelist to have a longer length.... see what works.... if still can't get it to work post a new question with your code and drop the link to the question here.